# I have one variable and print it and it prints '2'

Tags: java

```
try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("script.txt"));
            int i = 0;
            if (s.hasNext()){
                i = s.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(i);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

All is now right so thanks for the help. I found my mistake! :)

Comment: What do you expect to print? Of course it will display 5 because you modify its value before printing it in console.

Comment: Did you mean `else i = 5;`?

Comment: maybe he wants to tell us it prints two numbers at once? because he does s.nextline() at stdout

Comment: @TwelveDollar he doesn't print the value of `s.nextInt()` in this case.

Comment: if I run my programm i get
24 ( number from my .txt)        
5
so I get 2 numbers and just print 1Integer, thats weired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong if you expect to have only one number printed on console because:

```
try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("script.txt"));
            System.out.println(s.nextLine()); //<-- HERE YOU PRINT FIRST!
            int i = 0;
            if (s.hasNext()){
                i = s.nextInt();
            }
            i = 5;
            System.out.println(i); //<-- HERE YOU PRINT THE SECOND NUMBER!

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So you call twice `System.out.println()` which usually prints as method says, two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Because you assinged 5 to i just before you print i.

Comment: yeah so it should print just 5 but it doesn't it also Prints the number from the .txt before

Answer (score 0):

```
            i = 5;   // <--- You are assigning the value 5 here.
            System.out.println(i);  // <--- and printing it here.
```